# Скрытая Марковская модель HMM (почему отличаются прогнозы состояний? )

Tags: машинное-обучение, r, статистика

Сразу скажу что не являюсь экспертом в данной области, так что заранее извиняюсь если вопрос тривиальный.

Обучил СММ модель на данных, получаю разные прогнозы в зависимости от метода расчета прогноза, если прогнозировать вектор данных целиком то получаю один прогноз, а если прогноз делаю в скользящем окне то получаю другой прогноз

Вот простой и наглядный пример

создаем фейковые данные

```
train <- rnorm(1000)
test <- rnorm(30)
```

тренируем смм модель, всего два состояния

```
library(RHmm)
hmm <- HMMFit( train , nStates=2)
```

делаем прогноз(идентифицируем состояния) по новым данным

```
hmm.all.pred <- viterbi(hmm, test)$`states`
```

получаем вектор состояний

```
plot(hmm.all.pred,t="l",lwd=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И этот прогноз меня очень даже устраивает, но если делать прогноз скользящим окном, то прогноз становиться совсем другим и этот прогноз меня уже совсем не устраивает.

сделаем прогноз в скользящем окне размером 10 точек

```
hmm.local.pred <- rep(NA,length(test))

for(i in 10:length(test)){
  ii <- (i-9):i
  hmm.local.pred[i] <-  tail(    viterbi(hmm, test[ii])$`states`   ,  1)
}
```

скользящий прогноз красный

```
lines(hmm.local.pred,col=2,lwd=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в реальной ситуации  данные в модель то попадают как раз в виде вектора последних значений (в виде скользящего окна)

Вопрос могу ли я в скользящем окне получить такой же прогноз как в `hmm.all.pred` векторе? И вообще может кто то объяснить в чем собственно проблема? Кстати пробовал менять размер окна даже в несколько тысяч точек, прогноз все равно отличается и меня совсем не устраивает 
спасибо

Comment: Не знаю, как связаться с тобой, поэтому пишу здесь. По твоим вопросам на stack понимаю, что мы изучаем одно и тоже. Можешь дать какие-нибудь контакты, куда можно написать.

Comment: можно сюда mytarmail86@gmail.com